# Flutter StatefulWidget: How to Rebuild Widget When State is Updated Externally

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, statefulwidget

I'm encountering an issue with updating a variable within a **StatefulWidget** in Flutter. Specifically, I have a custom widget **CustomErrorFormField** which extends **StatefulWidget**. This widget contains a method **setErrorList** to update a list variable **errorList**. However, when **setErrorList** is called from another class, the **build** method in **CustomErrorFormField** does not reflect the updated **errorList**.

I understand that calling **setState** should trigger a rebuild of the widget, but I am unsure how to appropriately invoke **setState** in the **StatefulWidget** when the variable is updated from an external class. Here's the relevant code snippet for better understanding:

```
class CustomErrorFormField extends StatefulWidget {
  // Variable declaration
  List<String> errorList = [];

  // Method to update errorList
  void setErrorList(List<String> listOfError) {
    errorList = listOfError;
  }

  @override
  _CustomErrorFormFieldState createState() => _CustomErrorFormFieldState();
}

class _CustomErrorFormFieldState extends State<CustomErrorFormField> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Trying to print updated errorList, but not reflecting changes
    print(widget.errorList); 
    return ... // UI Code
  }
}
```

In another class, I'm updating the **errorList** like this:

```
// Instance creation and update
CustomErrorFormField nameTextFild = CustomErrorFormField(...);

// Inside some method
setState(() {
  // Updating errorList using setErrorList method
  if (condition) {
    nameTextFild.setErrorList([...]);
  } else {
    nameTextFild.setErrorList([...]);
  }
});
```

Comment: instead of `setErrorList` method you have to re-build your `CustomErrorFormField` widget and pass your `errorList` inside `CustomErrorFormField` constructor (like any other widgets do)

Comment: @pskink rebuilding it will cause the textfield to loose it's content. I want to just validate and send list of error to this custom Textfield which has a list view that can render those list of errors.

Comment: *"rebuilding it will cause the textfield to loose it's content."* - no, it will not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's **not** recommended that you change the state of a widget from outside the widget.

What you should do instead is pass the validation logic as a `function` and let the widget handle the state change.

**CustomFormField:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomErrorFormField extends StatefulWidget {
  //Take the validation logic as a parameter.
  final List<String> Function(String value) validator;
  const CustomErrorFormField({required this.validator});

  @override
  _CustomErrorFormFieldState createState() {
    return _CustomErrorFormFieldState();
  }
}

class _CustomErrorFormFieldState extends State<CustomErrorFormField> {
  
  //Keep the state inside the widget itself
  List<String> errorList = [];

  //Update the state from inside the widget
  void setErrorList(List<String> listOfError) {
    setState(() {
      errorList = listOfError;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      child: TextFormField(
        validator: (String value){
           //Use the validation logic to decide the error.
           setErrorList(widget.validator(value))
          }
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have used `TextFormField` as an example, you can use any widget that accepts a `callback` upon change.

If you're making everything from scratch you can attach the `validator` function to a `callback` that fires when the text is changed. Usually this is done with the help of a `controller`.

**usage:**

```
final nameTextFild = CustomErrorFormField(
  key: ValueKey(count),
  labelName: "Name",
  iContext: context,
  validator: (String value) {
    if (!value.contains(RegExp(r'[0-9]'))) {
      return [];
    } else {
      return ["Invalid characters, use letters only."];
    }
  },
);
```

Comment: Thanks but actually I wanted CustomErrorFormField as a separate widget that can be used many times with different validation logic. Using validation logic inside the widget will make it a dependent widget.

Comment: The code you takes validation as well as the state management logic as a parameter. In the code I provided, only the validation logic is taken as a parameter. So you can use the CustormErrorFormField with different validation logic.

Comment: But see you're setting ("Invalid characters, use letters only.") inside the CustomErrorFormField widget. I want to validate and send this list of errors from outside, so it can render those list of errors.

Comment: Since you just had an if statement, I made the code with just a `bool` in mind, changed the code to accommodate your needed behaviour. Changing the validator function's return type works .